# Free and intuitive Low Code/No Code MS PowerApps alternative for 80+ year old IT guy?

Tags: programming, elderly

My Grandfather would like resume his IT adventure and exercise his brain more. He's got a PhD when IT term hadn't been coined yet and was programming in 60s,70s,80s in languages like ALGOL, Basic etc. He tried to approach Python but it's a bit hard to follow for him these days and I'm .NET/Java programmer so I can figure out stuff but can't really lead him into Python. He's read about Microsoft PowerApps but as I've discovered there is no Community version only paid like 40$/month.

So is there any intuitive free alternative for Microsoft PowerApps(Low Code/No Code solution) that is good with data analysis?

PS: I'd like to create `Low Code`, `No Code` tags, but I don't have 150 rep yet.

Comment: I'd really recommend Python. All you need to do is stay one step ahead of him and it won't hurt you to learn Python either. The Anaconda distribution is a really good way to install Python as it includes a lot of useful stuff.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have some particular project in mind, you might like to consider him programming a tiny standalone board like the $10 BBC [micro:bit](https://microbit.org/) which is used by schools and can be programmed in a web GUI in an intuitive Lego bricks style, like Blockly or Scratch.  The same board can also introduce you to MicroPython, which is a stripped-down version of Python to fit in the microcontroller. The device just plugs into the usb and it is very rewarding to have something physical to play with.

There are other more sophisticated but tiny devices in a similar vein, such as from [m5stack](https://m5stack.com/) using MicroPython and their own GUI-in-a-web-page language.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you are trying to code. If you are looking at statistical data analysis then [KNIME](https://www.knime.com/knime-analytics-platform) is an option. It has sort of a visual programming environment where you wire up functional blocks. It takes some getting used to but there are decent learning resources on their site. The basic software is free.

[image]